# Creating a user for a given database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a user, setting the following parameters:

```
GRANT USAGE ON inventario.* TO cursoDistribuida@locahost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

I know this would not let user cursoDistribuida modify anything over inventario database, however, once I log to MySQL as cursoDistribuida, when I perform

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

I can't see the `inventario` database there, shouldn't `USAGE` let me see the database contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  the [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage):-

> The USAGE privilege specifier stands for "no privileges." It is used
>   at the global level with GRANT to modify account attributes such as
>   resource limits or SSL characteristics without affecting existing
>   account privileges.